# XSD: xs:sequence & xs:choice combination for xs:extension elements?

Tags: xml, inheritance, schema, xsd

My question is about defining an XML schema that will validate the following sample XML:

```
<rules>
    <other>...</other>
    <bool>...</bool>
    <other>...</other>
    <string>...</string>
    <other>...</other>
</rules>
```

The order of the child nodes does not matter. The cardinality of the child nodes is 0..unbounded.

All the child elements of the `rules` node have a common base type, `rule`, like so:

```
<xs:complexType name="booleanRule">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="rule">
            ...
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="stringFilterRule">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="filterRule">
            ...
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

My current attempt at defining the schema for the `rules` node is below. However,

1. **Can I nest `xs:choice` within `xs:sequence`? If, where do I specify the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute?**
2. **Is there a better way to do this, such as an `xs:sequence` which specifies only the base type of its child elements?**

   ```
       <xs:element name="rules">
           <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:choice>
                       <xs:element name="bool" type="booleanRule" />
                       <xs:element name="string" type="stringRule" />
                       <xs:element name="other" type="someOtherRule" />
                   </xs:choice>
               </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you can. You can specify `maxOccurs="unbounded"` where it better suits you. You can put it on `xs:choice`, for instance (I think that's what you're asking).
2. You can use substitution groups. See [this schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/1.1.0/expr.xsd) for example. `ogc:expression` is an abstract base element which may be substituted by different concrete expressions (`ogc:Add` and so on).

Comment: +1 & check @lexicore : For your suggestion on using substitution groups -  it seems a better way than putting `xs:choice` within an `xs:sequence`.